# How do I submit a patch to an ubuntu package which is using git?

Tags: packaging, launchpad, development

Some ubuntu packages are now using Launchpad's git support. e.g. apache2 https://code.launchpad.net/~usd-import-team/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+git/apache2

How do I create a Merge Request for such a package?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is documented here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Merging/GitWorkflow